# How can I remove all items from a Dojo dstore?

Tags: dojo, dgrid

I am having trouble removing all items from a dstore. I am trying this, which seems like it should work, but it fails at the end:

```
var TrackableMemory = declare([ Memory, Trackable ]);
var userMem = new TrackableMemory({
    data: {the data...},
    idProperty: '_id'
});    
userMem.forEach(function (userObj) {
    userMem.remove(userObj._id);
});
```

I put up a working (or not working, rather) example in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zz4mLw73/3/). See the console for the "cannot read property '_id' of undefined" error when it can't find the last record.

I have other things connecting to this store instance, so I can't really just reset everything by redefining `userMem`.

What am I doing wrong? How can I remove all items from a dstore?

Comment: Ah, seems like this might just be a JS array problem. e.g., `var a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']; a.forEach(function (letter) {var ind = a.indexOf(letter); a.splice(ind, 1);});`. Now `a` is `['b', 'd']`. Looks like this is what dstore is doing with its `forEach` function and Memory's `removeSync`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turned out to be a simple JS array problem of modifying the array over which I was iterating. Looping backwards over the array with a simple `for` works:

```
userMem.fetch().then(function (users){
    for (var i = users.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        userMem.remove(users[i]._id);
    }           
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
// Forget all data
myGrid.store.data = [];

// Refresh the grid
myGrid.refresh();
```